# How to Parameterize the values in ajax TruClient scripts

Tags: javascript, ajax, loadrunner, truclient

This is the scenario - 
There is a search criterion giving me 100 search results (100 Links). 
I want the virtual users to click on any of those links ramdomly. 
Can you please help me how manage this situation?

Comment: You need more information in your question to get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful to you? http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/Ajax-True-Client-parameterization-problem/td-p/5607543#.UDxLONYaNN9

Answer (score 0):

Your path is through correlating the links into an array, picking a random offset into the array and then a web_url to head to the link in question....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the help for the functions

```
web_reg_save_param()
web_reg_save_param_ex()
```

and especially the "Ord=All"/"Ordinal=All" parts in the help.

Then when you have captured the relevant data into an array you can use

```
lr_paramarr_random("TheArrayName");
```

to get a random value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether or not every listbox element is a valid selection. If the first element of the listbox is instructional ("Please select...", etc.), you need a snippet of code:

**Option 1:** (when a “Please select” is present)

In the step's 'Arguments' section, Set Ordinal to:

```
var objectIndex = Math.floor((object.length-1)*Math.random())+2;
objectIndex;
```

**Option 2:** (when a “Please select” is not present)

In the step's 'Arguments' section, Set Ordinal to “0”.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number in runtime and put that variable in the Ord= parameter. E.g.

```
a = Rand(1,100)
lr_save_param("{myrandval}",a);
Web_custome_request("",
"",
"",
"Ord={myrandval}",
LAST);
```